# Relief of frames

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, widget

I'm trying to make sunken frames in Tkinter. But somehow it always says that SUNKEN is not a viable option or valid word. Should I make it a string or does it not work for frames?

```py
root= tk()

master = Frame(root,width=300,height=300,relief=SUNKEN)
   
master.place(relx=0.1,rely=0.1,relwidth=0.8,relheight=0.8)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Your code is working as it should if `tk` is changed to `Tk`. Also, can you share the error message?

Comment: If you use `from tkinter import *`, then `SUNKEN` should be available, but `tk()` should be `Tk()`.  Also you should set `bd=1` in `Frame(...)`, otherwise you cannot see the relief.

Answer (score 0):

Just replace

```
root = tk()
```

with

```
root = Tk()
```